# Significado de "cinchar" en este contexto

Tags: sinónimos, argentina, significado-en-contexto, uruguay

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ip5NtZSYric

19:42

> **cinchar** como un animal para hacer lo que uno quiera...y que te garquen lo menos posible...para hacer cosas que te recopen

cinchar

> 1. tr. Asegurar la silla o albarda a un animal apretando la cincha.

> (pop.) Trabajar intensamente// hacer esfuerzos para que algo se realice como se desea// tirar con fuerza de una cuerda entre varias personas en grupos opuestos// apretar, ceñir/ / alentar, estar a favor de alguien.

> 3. intr. coloq. Arg. y Ur. Trabajar empeñosamente para que algo se realice.

> Verbo intransitivo
> 1 Trabajar duramente y con esfuerzo.
> Ámbito: Río de la Plata.
> Sinónimo: camellar (Colombia).

Lo que entiendo es que el que habla dice que el líder de un grupo debe ser como un burro de carga que lleve el proyecto adelante porque, lo quiera o no, es la médula espinal, tanto en el aspecto creativo como financiero, porque por eso es un líder, en su caso particular, dice que todos lo reconocen a él porque es más famoso y que por eso con el tiempo los demás quisieron tener sus temas propios y ganar más que él y con eso se equivocaron de cabo a rabo, porque cualquier tema que provenía del otro fue firmado por todos aunque los haya hecho él. Todos ganaban lo mismo siendo que el ponía los instrumentos, tecnología y más dinero.

¿Cinchar es imponerse, aguantar estoicamente, estar ahí presionando para que las cosas resulten como en un tira y afloja entre las partes o es trabajar duro, como en romperse el c**** trabajando, o ambas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el contexto provisto, relaciono:

"cinchar como un animal"

con el significado de "esforzarse" o, más metafóricamente, "tirar con fuerza de una cuerda". Este segundo significado da la idea de que hay una fuerza opuesta que dificulta o contrarresta el esfuerzo propio.